# Is Apéry's constant a rational multiple of $ \pi ^ 3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

It is well known that the values of the Riemann zeta function for even positive numbers are of the form:

$$\zeta(2k) = \rm rational * \pi ^{2k},$$

and more specifically $\zeta (2k)=(-1)^{{k+1}}{\frac  {B_{{2k}}(2\pi )^{{2k}}}{2(2k)!}}\!$. It is not that far-fetched to consider that

$$\zeta(2k + 1) = \rm rational * \pi ^{2k + 1}.$$

Specifically for Apéry's constant (which is $\zeta(3)$), did someone prove something like that? The proof should be something like:

> $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$ is rational / irrational / transcendental.

**EDIT**: Even if the question is still open (which I can see it is from the comments), is there any new development on this matter lately? Just curious.

Comment: No one has proved anything like this.

Comment: This is a well-known question, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60595/is-zeta3-pi3-rational).

Comment: A significant amount of effort has gone into this, but the nature of Apery's constant is still largely mysterious.

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem is open. But I would be rather surprised if $\large \frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$ turned out to be rational. My guess is that it is even transcendental (of course, only a guess). The continued fraction I calculated with PARI/GP with $20\ 000$ digits accuracy, contains $19501$ entries not exceeding $134656$. So, if the constant IS rational, numerator and denominator must be very large.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60595/is-zeta3-pi3-rational)

Comment: The series I have found series for $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$, $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^4}$ are slow to converge, which means they are not suited for application in Apéry style irrationality proofs. For example $\lambda(3)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta(2k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$ and $\lambda(3)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda(2k)}{(k+1)(2k+1)}$ where $\lambda(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^n}$ and $\beta(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)^n}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Apéry proved in 1978 that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, the irrationality of $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$ is still an open problem. There are some formulas expressing odd zeta values in terms of powers of $\pi$, the most known ones are due to Plouffe and Borwein & Bradley. Here are some examples:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\zeta(3)&=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)},\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\,\binom {2n}n} &= -\frac{4}{3}\,\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 3^2}\,\left(\zeta(2, \tfrac{1}{3})-\zeta(2,\tfrac{2}{3}) \right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Moreover, in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/a-new-formula-for-aperys-constant-and-other-zetas) we have:

$$
\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(3) = \frac{\pi^3}{24}\sqrt{2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3(e^{\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3(e^{2\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}.
$$

You can also check out [this paper by Vepstas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775v4.pdf), which provides a nice generalization to some of these identities.